# How to make Fotorama Slider to resume slides autoplay once a video is played and ends in the slider?

Tags: slider, autoplay, fotorama

I want the Fotorama slider to resume the autoplay of video slides after video play in slider.

Here is a more clear picture of what I want.

1. Fotorama video slider slides all the videos.
2. User clicks on a slide and the slide plays the video in it.
3. Once the video ends the slider continues playing the slides.

Please can someone help me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

No way. Fotorama only attaches/detaches iframes and doesn’t know the state of playback.

To do what you want you need to connect with Player Javascript API (YouTube for example). It goes beyond a tiny plugin.

Comment: Is it possible to be done with vimeo. Please can you help with this ?